# Regex Expression to convert data into valid JSON

Tags: regex, aggregation-framework, regex-group

i have a string like this:

```
{
    1=9592022964
    2=959777666006
}
{
    1=9592022964
    2=959777666006
    }
```

now i am trying to convert this into valid json. i am able to convert by using multiple single expressions is it any way to convert in singel expression?

desired output:

```
{"1":"9592022964","2":"959777666006"}
{"1":"9592022964","2":"959777666006"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex expression. `(\w+)=(\w+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sn9xwX/1)

Comment: its working fine but i need to pass entire line as valid json and remove the ; for last element. how can i do this?

Comment: @user6325753  Are you saying that there is a "," after the last element? This "," does not affect the json object. If you want to remove it, a regular expression is not well done.